# First multisig using Armory

Tags: public-key, armory, multi-signature

I hope that no such question already has appeared here. I've searched for a solution but cannot find one.

My problem is as follows:
I want to use multisig with Armory on Linux. I've created new wallet, new address and changed Armory to Expert mode, since that is the mode for using Multisig/Lockboxes etc. In order to that I need need my address' public key. So I've checked it - these are two numbers - coordinates of an elliptic curve (I'm a newbie here as you can see :3). I wonder - how can I obtain my address' pubkey in a starting with 02, 03 or 04, as a one string. I've tried ECDSA calc built it Armory, but it's not that. I suppose I need to express it in HEX or sth. I need it to obtain my multisig pubkey.

Please, help
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you make your question more clear?  Are you asking specifically how to get the public key of an address generated in Armory?  Are you asking about the different formats of public keys in ECDSA (compressed or not)?  Making the question more clear will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to first load watch-only wallets of the multisig lockbox you hope to create. Say, you want 2-of-3 and you have 3 watch-only wallets.

Go to Lockboxes -> Create Lockbox -> and click the address book icon next to each public key #1. Highlight the wallet you want the public key to be from and select an address below that hasn't been used yet. Repeat for public key #2 and public key #3. Generally, you should be choosing from different watch-only wallets.

Click Save Lockbox and you now have a new multi-sig p2sh address!

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I don't know why isn't it written anywhere in Armory.. at least I didn't see it. Ok, but do I need that much? I only want one pubkey to send someone..

Comment: It is (I was an Armory developer). I forget exactly where, but it's there somewhere. What multisig do you want to make if not 2-of-3? 1-of-2?

Comment: Oh nice then.. The book doesn't open any new window :( It would be 2-2 multisig.

Comment: Do you have the wallets imported? Which version of Armory? You might want to file a bug here: https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory/issues